# GWT capturing keyboard events on Composite

Tags: gwt

I am trying to capture keyboard events when there isn't a widget with the focus.  I tried adding this to a composite widget :

```
    addDomHandler(new KeyPressHandler(){
        public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
            logger.info("onKeyPress: "+event);
        }
    }, KeyPressEvent.getType());
```

but I am not trapping the keyboard events.  I'd like to be able to determine when the `Ctrl` key is press whilst a `mousedown` event is occuring.  How can I do that?

Comment: you can always override the onBrowseeEvent();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MouseDownHandler:

```
MouseDownHandler mouseDownHandler = new MouseDownHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onMouseDown(MouseDownEvent event) {
        if (event.isControlKeyDown()) {
            // do something
        }
    }

};
myCompositeWidget.addDomHandler(mouseDownHandler, MouseDownEvent.getType());
```